# Render media url in node--page.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, media, uri

I have an Entity reference field `field_video`. It's a core Media field with a Reference type of Remote video.

Because I use this `field_video` in my Hero section I need some additional markup here.

From the admin `node/add/page`, the editor can insert a Youtube remote video (url).

When I debug the page I see the following variables (see screenshot).

[image]

How do I render the media url in `node--page.html.twig`? Then I am able to build the correct HTML markup and styling around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `uri` of remote video in `node--page.html.twig` try with:

```
node.field_video.entity.field_media_oembed_video.value
```

Comment: Thanks that's working. How could I have debugged this? I am using Xdebug and PhpStorm to debug.

Comment: I use https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper module and i dump the  entity 
 `{{ dump(node.field_video.entity) }}` to see the the fields inside the referenced entity